# Syntax errors when trying to calculate the average distance between points and (0,0)

Tags: python, math, lambda, data-science

I am trying to Calculate the average distance of these points from the point (0,0).I seem to be getting errors and I am unsure what the problem is. Below is what I have done

```
coordinates = [(0,1), (3,4), (-5,12), (2,2)]
```

`print (coordinates)`

```
import math
def distance(x1, y1, x2, y2):
     return math.sqrt(square(x2-x1) + square(y2-y1))
def square(value):
    return value * value

distances = list(map(lambda (x,y): distance(0,0,x,y), coordinates))
average = reduce(lambda p,q: p + q, distances)/float(len(distances))
print (average)
```

I keep getting the following error

```py
File "<ipython-input-103-76dd44055d43>", line 7
    distances = list(map(lambda (x,y): distance(0,0,x,y), coordinates))
                                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Remove the parentheses around x,y

Comment: @quamrana I just did.. multiple errors

Comment: I think you need to ask another question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import math
import numpy as np

coordinates = [(0,1), (3,4), (-5,12), (2,2)]
def distance(x1, y1, x2, y2):
     return math.sqrt(square(x2-x1) + square(y2-y1))
def square(value):
    return value * value
distances = list(map(lambda x: distance(0,0,x[0],x[1]), coordinates))
print(np.mean(distances))
5.457106781186548
```

Comment: can you please explain how you were able to solve the problem and the error with my codes so I can understand? thanks

Comment: That is how the lambda function  see the data. The function see x as (0,1), in the first case.  If x=(0,1) then x[0]=0 and x[1]=1.

Comment: Thanks alot. God bless